# Why don't prime counting approximations work for Brocard's conjecture?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, asymptotics, conjectures

So the number of primes $\le n$ is like $n/\log n$, and so the $n$th prime is like $n \log n$.

Great, so $p_{n}^2 = n^2 \log^2 n$, and so the number of primes smaller would then be

$$\frac{n^2 \log^2 n}{\log(n^2 \log^2 n)}$$

Therefore, we can say the number of primes inbetween $p_n^2$ and $p_{n+1}^2$ would be like

$$f(n)=\frac{(n+1)^2 \log^2 (n+1)}{\log((n+1)^2 \log^2 (n+1))}
-\frac{n^2 \log^2 n}{\log(n^2 \log^2 n)}$$

[[image: graph of <span class=]$f$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQz1x.png)

As you can see, $f(n)>4$ whenever $n>n_0$ for some $n_0$, and the limit of $f$ as $n\to \infty$ clearly is infinity.

So my question is, first of all, all I've done is extremely obvious and every mathematician who tried this problem likely started here, or eventually ended up here one way or another, so this line of thinking has probably been studied somewhere. I'm curious where specifically these approximations fail. It's not like these are bad approximations. You know, we can use similar things with another term in each to upper and lower bound specifically, and try to squeeze somehow. But I don't even bother trying, because I know that any other mathematician would have done it already because what I wanted to try is tedious but overall trivial.

So where are the resources for where tries of this problem have been worked out? Where do these approximations fall apart when you try to use similar lower and upper bounds to constitute a proof. I mean, all we need to show is that the true $f$ has $f > 4$ for large enough $n$. So, y'know, where does this go wrong, when the approximation looks to be increasing as $n\to\infty$? This problem looks very easy but in actuality there is no way to tie things up? So unbelievably frustrating. But I want to see when you have a mathematician try this with various lower and upper bounds where specifically they all go wrong in showing that $f>4$, thank you.

Comment: I guess it seems that with $f$ going to infinity we can hope that we could simply prove it is larger than, say, 4.. But with the twin primes, when you start to analyze you realize you are depending on max of a noise to be just greater than 1 infinitely often. They are fundamentally completely different to work with as approximations, and this one feels far more tractable to handle than for the twin prime one.

Comment: @MartinR I disagree. This argument would NOT work for twin primes since $n/\log n - (n-3)/\log(n-3) < 1$ for $n>4$. The reason I would hope this argument works for Brocard's is that I'm getting that the number of primes between squared primes is growing with the size of $n$, so I was hoping that a bounding argument would be enough to show that at least $f>4$ after some manual checking.

Comment: @MartinR Did you not understand the question? I understand $p_n^2 \neq n^2\log^2 n$ and how to deal with a specific bounding depends on tangible choices and known bounds. Don't use this one specifically, just ones related and very close to these ones I've written here.

Comment: @MartinR you misunderstood my use of the word "like", but that's alright. Yes, that is what my question is asking. And the $f$ is an approximation but we are interested in the true distribution of number of primes between prime squares.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm asking for a reference where people have worked through all the various prime counting lower and upper bounds with regards to how I defined that composition above. It is far too natural for no-one to have tried, but I couldn't find where it was discussed, so I was hoping to start that list here.

Comment: $x/log(x) < pi(x) < 1.25506 x / log(x)$ for example holds for $x \ge 17$. So where are the attempts of people using these bounds in the way I described in the question to prove this conjecture?

Comment: @MartinR Sure, but why are you bringing that up? That is not related to my question here in the slightest. I'm not claiming this to be a proof, but anyway.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for letting me know so I can take a picture before they're gone. Anyway, I figured out the answer to this question, but I guess nobody really cares to know why this approximation fails here, so I'll keep it to myself.

Comment: @MartinR https://i.imgur.com/bqXHSg6.png also the "why the downvote" is @ the downvoter not you, just to be clear.. but you responded anyway as if I were chatting directly to you.. Funny stuff, well, thanks anyway but I figured it out (hint: that $f$ only goes to infinity if the coefficients are exactly equal, sadly it will go to -infinity if you choose 1.0001* the negative term.)

Comment: Anyway I'm going to delete the question now

Comment: well I guess I can just answer it

Comment: who would have thought a simple to state conjecture about prime numbers would be difficult to prove XD sorry for my snappiness. Thanks Martin, and everyone, please take care!

Answer (score 1):

Estimates for the number of primes up to n are reasonably precise. But they are smooth real valued functions, while the exact number of primes is integer valued, is constant most of the time and jumps by one from time to time.

If you want to estimate the number of primes from n to m, you could take f(m) - f(n-1) where f is any estimate. But if the difference between n and m is much smaller than m, the relative error will be much larger. You can estimate the number of primes up to n = 10^18 and up to n + 1,000,000 quite precisely, compared to n / ln n, but the error will be large compared to 1,000,000 or 1,000,000 / ln 1,000,000.

Comment: Sure, but all you need is that f(m)-f(n-1) is positive (at least 4) where all the asymptotics actually go to infinity. So even a large error would be acceptable - but in this case, if you multiply the second term by any $x>1$, you get negative infinitely many primes between them - uh-oh. That's where those estimates fail for this particular problem..

Answer (score -2):

Hint:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2 \log^2 (n+1)}{\log((n+1)^2 \log^2 (n+1))}
-\frac{(1+\epsilon)n^2 \log^2 n}{\log(n^2 \log^2 n)} = -\infty$$
Whenever $\epsilon>0$. Therefore, it is not enough even that $x/\log x < \pi(x) < \frac{4x}{3\log(x)}$, where $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes less than $x$. You would need that limit above to go to $+\infty$ for $\epsilon \in [0, 1/3]$, which is simply not true.

Comment: why the delete posts? Do you not think this is a reasonable question and answer? I think it perfectly answers the question for why this approximation fails to produce a proof of Brocard's Conjecture.

Comment: Perhaps you aren't satisfied that I did not prove the hint? But it is true, you may check it in many ways.